# How to serve two web applications from one domain and different paths?

Tags: nginx, dnsmasq

I have a web app which can be accessed from `http://example.com`
I'm developing locally another web app which I want to access it from the same domain but different path. Let's say I want all traffic from `http://example.com/my-local-app/*` go to my web app served from `localhost:8080`. All other requests should go to remote `http://example.com`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider nginx Reverse Proxy.

Example :

```
location ~ /my-local-app {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
}
```

In this situation, if any request comes to **/my-local-app** nginx will forward internally to localhost and return the response as well.

Comment: The problem is that I want to direct part of traffic to from one domain to localhost and another part to remote host.

Comment: You can also do that by proxy_pass.  proxy_pass http://remotehostip:80/;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `virtualhosts` for your two applications. One application will be accessible from `http://first.example.com` and another will be using `http://second.example.com`. You cannot run one web server on two different ports. Another option is to use `nginx` as you are using now and install `apache` on the same machine but configure `apache` server to run on a different port (8080) whereas `nginx` is running on port 80. Although not recommended, this would mean you need to manage two different web servers instead of one.

`virtualhosts` is the way IMO.

Comment: I need to serve both apps from the exact same domain, only paths define the final destination of request.